# Посоветуйте С# работа с текстом (поиск текста)

Tags: c#, поиск, текст

Есть один файл (txt). В нем записаны номера карт (**1 800 000** шт.).

### пример:

```
000001000001097
000001000001213
000001000001268
000001000001291
000001000001365
000001000001376
000001000001398
```

### Задача:

Нужно проверить есть ли такой номер карты который был введен.
И проверить **быстро**!
Проверяться будет **часто** из одного запуска програмы.

### Что я уже написал:

```
StreamReader str = new StreamReader("Blacklist.txt", Encoding.Default);
            while (!str.EndOfStream)
            {
                string st = str.ReadLine();
                if (st.StartsWith(tb_cardinput.Text))
                {
                    textBox1.Text = st;
                    break;// останавливаем цикл
                }
            }
            str.Close();
```

### Вопрос

Мне кажется что это должно быть написано не так. Ведь как мне кажется было бы лучше например один раз загрузить весь файл в переменную и в ней искать или в массив. Как лучше сделать в этой ситуации? А главное чтобы искало быстро?

### Проблема

Почему код что я написал всегда возвращает первую строку!

### P.S.

Я в C# новенький (1 неделя). Поделитесь пожалуста советами и если есть примерами)
а так C# очень нравится!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var cardsNumbers = File.ReadAllLines("Blacklist.txt");
var LogHashSet = new HashSet<string>(cardsNumbers);

bool isExist = LogHashSet.Contains("000001000001365");
```

[Пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009107/what-net-collection-provides-the-fastest-search), что по HashSet поиск самый быстрый.

Переменную LogHashSet храните в классе и каждый раз вызывайте метод Contains.

**UPD:** @DreamChild предложил использовать бинарный поиск (сам сначала думал так предложить). Чтобы не быть голословным, решил сделать тесты (тесты проводился на 10 миллионах чисел).

---

**Тест первый** - в качестве массива для хранения номеров карт string[]:

*Время создания массива cardsNumbers* - 3 секунды

*Памяти необходимо под массив cardsNumbers* - 544 мегабайт

- HashSet

*Время поиска* - 15 Ticks т.е. 1,5 микросекунды

*Необходимо памяти* - 156 мегабайт

- BinarySearch

*Время поиска* - 1018 Ticks при не сортированном массиве и 512 Ticks при сортированном. Этот момент странен тем, что массив я отдаю сортированный, но вызов метода Sort увеличивает скорость поиска в 2 раза. Возможно, массив располагается каким-то образом в памяти.

*Вызов метода Sort* - 36 секунд (вызов делается 1 раз, но подождать придётся)

*Необходимо памяти* - 39 мегабайт.

---

**Тест второй** - в качестве массива для хранения номеров карт int[]:

*Время создания массива cardsNumbers* - 6~8 секунд

*Памяти необходимо под массив cardsNumbers* - 47 мегабайт

- HashSet

*Время поиска* - 100~200 Ticks

*Необходимо памяти* - 156 мегабайт

- BinarySearch

*Время поиска* - 400~500 Ticks. Теперь уже вызов метода Sort не даёт увеличения скорости поиска.

*Необходимо памяти* - 39 мегабайт.

---

**Вывод:**

Создавая массив int:

*Плюсы:*

- мы экономим 497 мегабайт;
- нет необходимости сортировать массив для бинарного поиска (экономим 36 секунд на старте приложения);
- бинарный поиск по сортированному массиву почти эквивалентен поиску по int массиву;

*Минусы:*

- теряем при старте приложения 3~5 секунд;
- скорость поиска HashSet уменьшается в 10 раз.

Создавая массив string:

*Плюсы:*

- имеем самую высокую скорость поиска - 15 Ticks = 1,5 микросекунды;

*Минусы:*

- под массив cardsNumbers необходимо 544 мегабайт памяти.

Итак:

- если у Вас достаточно памяти, то используйте HashSet и храните cardsNumbers в массиве String[];
- если у Вас мало памяти, то используйте обычный List и бинарный поиск, а cardsNumbers храните в int[] массиве.

---

**UPD2**
Пример кода:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cards = new Cards();
            Console.WriteLine(cards.Contains("000001000001365"));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Cards
    {
        private const string PATH_TO_FILE = "Blacklist.txt";
        private HashSet<string> cardsNumbers;

        public Cards()
        {
            var cardsNumbersFromFile = File.ReadAllLines(PATH_TO_FILE);
            cardsNumbers = new HashSet<string>(cardsNumbersFromFile);
        }

        public bool Contains(string value)
        {
            return cardsNumbers.Contains(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! ваш пример работает!
У меня есть еще вопрос... как мне записать:
var LogHashSet = new HashSet<string>(cardsNumbers);
в свой клас? (например test1). Когда пишу:
public var cardNumbersLogHash { get; set; }
ошибка с var. Если вместо var - object то проблема потом с методом Contains

Comment: Отличный ответ!

Comment: Вы можете ускорить работу, пользуясь `File.ReadLines` вместо `File.ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, в вашем случае есть смысл воспользоватться  [алгоритмом бинарного поиска](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) - он позволяет не перебирать весь файл, чтобы проверить наличие или отсутствие в нем той или иной строки. Единственный его минус - требование, чтобы исходная последовательность была отсортирована. Однако в приведенном вами примере данные как раз упорядочены.

Comment: Бинарный поиск по идее быстрее: не надо читать _весь_ файл в память. (Для одного искомого элемента.)

Comment: @VladD Бинарный поиск на диске? Могет быть, могет быть. Только я в современных файловых системах слабо ориентируюсь. Если можно найти хвост файла не просматривая его, то да. Опять же для одиночного поиска. При массовом он всё равно окажется в кеше.

Comment: @alexlz: размер строки одинаков, такшта начало каждой строки расположено по фиксированному смещению. Ну и файлы на Вендах вполне себе произвольного доступа (а до-диез скорее всего обозначает именно форточки, а не Моно). Это, конечно, всё так, если размер кластера сильно меньше размера файла, и если мы и правда получим выигрыш, не загружая весь файл в память.

---
Для массового поиска, понятно, лучше всего предобработка (то есть `HashSet<int>`).

Comment: @VladD фиксированный размер строки избавляет от необходимости искать начало/конец строки. А вот как стандартными вызовами определить смещение конца файла (в смысле ftell). Не читая файл целиком. Может и несложно, но искать лениво. Так что секрет -- в студию

Comment: @alexlz: например, [`FileStream.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.length.aspx) (размер) и [`FileStream.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position.aspx) (установка в нужную позицию).

Вот подтверждение того, что `Length` не требует предварительного чтения файла: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9178681/276994 (Вы думаете, что виндушный file manager, показывая размеры файлов, читает их полностью?)

Comment: @VladD Да не, при отображении директории размер берётся из оглавления (в случае юникслайков -- из inode), но вот реализация потоковых методов -- тут я неграмотен, увы.

Comment: @alexlz: Ну да, а что ж, `FileStream` тупее Проводника? Вы разработчиков .NET совсем уж за лохов держите.

(Конечно, если использовать не `FileStream`, а просто абстрактный `Stream`, который может быть на самом деле и `FileStream`, и `HttpStream` — тогда да, размер не известен заранее.)

Comment: @VladD это по неграмотности. Поскольку о .net я если немного и знаю, то понаслышке. 

А вообще, даже с базовым набором файловых вызовов это несложно: fseek(..., ..., SEEK_END). Так что: "всылил. Был неправ"

Answer (score 1):

> Ведь как мне кажется было бы лучше например один раз загрузить весь файл в переменную и в ней

Ну так создайте массив типа string и в цикле заполните его значениями из str.

> Почему код что я написал всегда возвращает первую строку!

Мне кажется что это

```
if (st.StartsWith(tb_cardinput.Text))
```

Лучше заменить на это:

```
if (st === (tb_cardinput.Text))
```

Ибо StartSwitch делает так: *Определяет, совпадает ли **начало** данного экземпляра строки с указанной строкой*

Сам C# второй день изучаю.